# Isotropy/little group of $O(n)$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-space-isomorphism, grassmannian

I'm trying to prove that the little group of $O(n)$ acting on a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, call it $V$, is $O(k)\times O(n - k)$ due to the Grassmann manifold is isomorphic to $O(n)/(O(k)\times O(n - k))$.

I tried following the next steps: for elements in the little group, call them $g_l$, $q \in V$ has to be invariant, that is $g_lq = q$ and therefore:

$$g_l = \begin{pmatrix}1_k & 0 \\0 & A_{n - k} \end{pmatrix}    \tag1$$

Where $1_k$ is the $k\times k$ identity matrix and $A_{n-k}$ a $(n - k)\times (n - k)$ matrix. A similar process can be seen in [Isotropy group of $SO(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076569/isotropy-group-of-son). I presume that $A_{n - k} \in O(n - k)$ because we are working with orthonormal transformations.

Therefore, we conclude that the little group is $1_k\times O(n - k)$ which is different from the deduction by the isomorphism for Grassmann manifold.

I'm doing something bad but I don't know what. Can you show me the way?

Comment: First, in English, we say "subgroup" rather than "little group." So your mistake is that $1_k$ can be any orthogonal transformation preserving $q$. This is isomorphic to $O(k)$, not just the identity. (Take $q$, in particular, to be the subspace $\Bbb R^k\times\{0\}$.) And, of course, $A_{n-k}$ must be orthogonal, as well.

Comment: First, for 'little group' I didn't mean 'subgroup' but 'isotropic' which are synonymous. And second, my mistake is quite related to what you say. Instead of thinking in whole spaces ($q = \mathbb{R}^k\times\{0\}$), I was thinking in particular vectors ($q \in \mathbb{R}^k\times\{0\}$). So thanks for your contribution

Comment: "Isotropy subgroup" is what you mean :)

Comment: That's it. The slash between 'isotropic' and 'little' was just to put together both names. And again thanks for your contribution, it enlightened me

Comment: You're most welcome.